# Procedure Call Standard for the ARM® Architecture: 2 separate, but related return values

Tags: assembly, arm, calling-convention

Function `readWord` should return:

- status code (error or success, e.g., 0 = success, > 0 error codes)
- data read from a data source (only valid if the status code represents success)

Is the following example following AAPCS?
Is there a better way to do this considering AAPCS?

```
// OUT:
//  R0 (status code): 0 if valid, else > 0
//  R1 (data):  
//  if the R0 represents a successful read: data, which was read,
//  else: undetermined
read32:
    PUSH    {LR}

    LDR     R0, =memoryMappedAddressOfDataSource
    LDR     R4, [R0]
    BL      checkValidRead
    // If the read was invalid, directly return the error 
    // code set by checkValidRead in R0 and do not change R1.
    CBNZ    R0, read32_return

    // R0 is 0, so the read was valid and the the data is returned in R1.
    MOV     R1, R4

read32_return:  
    POP     {PC}

// IN: none
// Checks a special status register to determine, 
// whether the last read was successful.    
// OUT:
//  R0: 0 if valid, else > 0
checkValidRead:
    ...
```

From the [AAPCS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) (page 18):

> A double-word sized Fundamental Data Type (e.g., long long, double and 64-bit containerized vectors) is returned in r0 and r1.
>
> A Composite Type larger than 4 bytes, or whose size cannot be determined statically by both caller and
>   callee, is stored in memory at an address passed as an extra argument when the function was called (§5.5,
>   rule A.4). The memory to be used for the result may be modified at any point during the function call.

However, I do not know if it is rather a containerized 64-bit vector or an aggregate composite type or even sth. else:

> The content of a containerized vector is opaque to most of the procedure call standard: the only defined aspect of
>   its layout is the mapping between the memory format (the way a fundamental type is stored in memory) and
>   different classes of register at a procedure call interface.
>
> A Composite Type is a collection of one or more Fundamental Data Types that are handled as a single entity at
>   the procedure call level. A Composite Type can be any of:
>   An aggregate, where the members are laid out sequentially in memory [...]

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what type the caller of the function is going to use, assuming that the caller isn't also written assembly, but what you describe more naturally fits the definition of a composite type (eg. a C structure value). If the caller is written in assembly then you may not need to follow the calling convention all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc you quoted says that any composite types which don't fit in a single register are returned via hidden pointer.  This would include a C struct.

*Only* a single wide integer or FP type can be returned in a register pair.

A register pair is more efficient than store/reload through a hidden pointer, so it's unfortunate that you have to hack around the calling convention instead of just returning a `struct { uint32_t flag, value; }`

**To describe the calling convention you want to a C compiler, you tell it you're returning a `uint64_t`, and split that up into two 32-bit integer variables**.  This will happen for free because the compiler already has them in separate registers.

For example (source + asm [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint64_t+read32(void)%3B%0A%0Aunion+unpack32+%7B%0A++++uint64_t+u64%3B%0A++++uint32_t+u32%5B2%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+ext(uint32_t)%3B++++++++//+something+to+do+with+a+return+value%0A%0Aunsigned+read32_wrapper()+%7B%0A++++union+unpack32+ret+%3D+%7B+read32()+%7D%3B%0A++++if+(ret.u32%5B0%5D)+%7B%0A++++++++ext(ret.u32%5B1%5D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+ret.u32%5B0%5D%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:68.2587064676617,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)',t:'0')),l:'4',m:31.74129353233831,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).  I used a union, but you could equally use a shift.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t read32(void);

union unpack32 {
    uint64_t u64;
    uint32_t u32[2];
};

void ext(uint32_t);        // something to do with a return value

unsigned read32_wrapper() {
    union unpack32 ret = { read32() };
    if (ret.u32[0]) {
        ext(ret.u32[1]);
    }
    return ret.u32[0];
}
```

compiles like this:

```
    push    {r4, lr}
    bl      read32
    subs    r4, r0, #0          @ set flags and copy the flag to r4

    movne   r0, r1
    blne    ext                 @ the if() body.

    mov     r0, r4              @ always return the status flag
    pop     {r4, lr}
    bx      lr
```

Comment: In the OPs case, a separate pointer to pointer in R1 might make as much or more sense.  You may return multiple values in 'C' by using pointers.  Using unions might result in as much synthetic overhead as the memory write/read associated with pointers as the compiler tries to juggle registers.  Also, pointers will work on many architectures.  If the 'R1' value was 'hot' then it would be better to use in-line assembler.  There are other ways to handle exceptions/error codes as well; like a longjmp() or C++ exceptions.  However, this is a fine direct answer to the question.

Comment: @artlessnoise: then their callee would have to save/restore `r1` across `bl checkValidRead`, and do an `str`.  Then the caller would have to reload that store, introducing store-forwarding latency.  This answer shows that you can get the effect of two return values in two registers with *zero* cost by telling the calling convention it's a `uint64_t`.  The union is just for unpacking it; the calling convention doesn't see the union.   This answer shows that gcc compiles this unpacking code with *zero* overhead.  (And nothing about the union escapes `read32_wrapper`, it could be defined inside.)

Comment: The caller typically moves 'R4' to 'R1' and doesn't need to restore anything if it will be used afterwards; it may vary depending on the caller. Also, the pointer is to a memory block, so if it is being accessed, these 'store forward latency' issues are small compared to what is being done.  Also, you neglect the comment on using inline assembler if this did matter.  My main point is that they have probably structured things in the wrong way.  Also, it is possible to use the low bit of the pointer as a return code, if memory is aligned.

Comment: @artlessnoise: those are good points for this problem specifically (especially using the low bit of an aligned pointer, or for error-or-pointer it's either an odd error code or an even pointer).  I was more interested in the general case of returning 2 values.  You could write another answer about this use-case; I don't think I'm going to expand this answer for that.